# Evaluate the one sided limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 9^{-}}\frac{ x^2 − 9x}{x^2 − 18x + 81}$

Tags: calculus

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 9^{-}}\frac{x^2 − 9x}{x^2 − 18x + 81}$$

Now since the value of 9 is coming from the left side, I substituted 8.99 for x however, after doing so all my values after calculating them are negative on the top and bottom, Thus, why is the answer negative infinity?

Comment: On the bottom are positive, since $x^2-18x+81=(x-9)^2>0$ for any $x\ne 9.$

Answer (score 1):

This equals $$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{9-h}{9-h-9}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{9-h}{-h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{9}{-h}+1=-\infty$$

Comment: You can't plug in 9, it is a limit.

Comment: I've not plugged in 9! In first step I cancelled the common terms and then I replaced $x\to 9$ with $h\to 0$ and putted $x=9-h$

Answer (score 0):

For $\ x\to9^-:$

$$\lim_{x\to{9^-}}\frac{x^2-9x}{x^2-18x+81}=\lim_{x\to{9^-}}\frac{x(x-9)}{(x-9)^2}=\lim_{x\to{9^-}}\frac{x}{x-9}=\frac{9}{0^-}=-\infty$$

Comment: So I should factor first and then substitute 8.99?

Comment: yes, because if you directly substitute you get an indetermined form $\ 0/0$

Comment: You can't plug in 9. It is a limit.

Comment: what I want to say is that if you do not simplify in that way you get an indetermined form

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 9^-}\frac{x^2-9x}{x^2-18x+81}=\lim_{x\to 9^-}\frac{x(x-9)}{(x-9)^2}=\lim_{x\to 9^-}\frac{x}{x-9}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{9-\epsilon}{9-\epsilon-9}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{9-\epsilon}{-\epsilon}=-\infty$$